# Delete certain values inside a column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, sql-update

I want to delete certain values inside a column ,i have a column definition that contain this for example:

```
<listdef page="25" default_order="entity" default_order_type="a"><reportId>1332</reportId><name>test</name><description>test</description><multiProduct>N</multiProduct><product_code>BG,</product_code><equivalentCurrency>EUR</equivalentCurrency><use_absolute_width>Y</use_absolute_width><column name="ref_id"><description locale="fr">Système Id</description></column><column name="iss_date"><description locale="fr">Date d'émission</description></column><column name="exp_date"><description locale="fr">Date de Validité</description></column><column name="bg_amt"><description locale="fr">Montant de la Garantie Bancaire</description></column><column name="applicant_name"><description locale="fr">Nom du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column name="entity"><description locale="fr">Entité</description></column><column name="applicant_reference"><description locale="fr">Référence du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column width="5%" name="action"><url action="y"><parameter column="ref_id" name="REFERENCE_ID"/><parameter column="product_code" name="PRODUCT_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="HISTORY" name="OPTION_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="LIST_INQUIRY" name="OPERATION_CODE"/><parameter value="TRADEADMIN_SCREEN" name="SCREEN"/></url></column><column name="bg_liab_amt" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><column name="product_code" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><parameter input="y" name="ENTITE" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">ENTITE</description></parameter><parameter input="y" name="TIERS" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">TIERS</description></parameter><parameter name="export_list" file="stock CBC" type="export" file_name="stock CBC"/><candidate name="BG"><filter><criteria><column name="entity" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">ENTITE</value></criteria><criteria><column name="applicant_reference" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">TIERS</value></criteria></filter></candidate><aggregate type="count"><column name="ref_id"/><description locale="fr">Nombre de dossiers</description></aggregate><aggregate type="sum" cur="EUR"><column name="bg_liab_amt"/><description locale="fr">Total encours</description></aggregate><executable_flag>Y</executable_flag></listdef>
```

what i want is to delete this part and keep the rest:

```
<column width="5%" name="action"><url action="y"><parameter column="ref_id" name="REFERENCE_ID"/><parameter column="product_code" name="PRODUCT_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="HISTORY" name="OPTION_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="LIST_INQUIRY" name="OPERATION_CODE"/><parameter value="TRADEADMIN_SCREEN" name="SCREEN"/></url></column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using a combination of the `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` function as follows:

```
WITH YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_COL) AS
(SELECT
    q'{<listdef page="25" default_order="entity" default_order_type="a"><reportId>1332</reportId><name>test</name><description>test</description><multiProduct>N</multiProduct><product_code>BG,</product_code><equivalentCurrency>EUR</equivalentCurrency><use_absolute_width>Y</use_absolute_width><column name="ref_id"><description locale="fr">Système Id</description></column><column name="iss_date"><description locale="fr">Date d'émission</description></column><column name="exp_date"><description locale="fr">Date de Validité</description></column><column name="bg_amt"><description locale="fr">Montant de la Garantie Bancaire</description></column><column name="applicant_name"><description locale="fr">Nom du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column name="entity"><description locale="fr">Entité</description></column><column name="applicant_reference"><description locale="fr">Référence du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column width="5%" name="action"><url action="y"><parameter column="ref_id" name="REFERENCE_ID"/><parameter column="product_code" name="PRODUCT_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="HISTORY" name="OPTION_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="LIST_INQUIRY" name="OPERATION_CODE"/><parameter value="TRADEADMIN_SCREEN" name="SCREEN"/></url></column><column name="bg_liab_amt" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><column name="product_code" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><parameter input="y" name="ENTITE" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">ENTITE</description></parameter><parameter input="y" name="TIERS" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">TIERS</description></parameter><parameter name="export_list" file="stock CBC" type="export" file_name="stock CBC"/><candidate name="BG"><filter><criteria><column name="entity" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">ENTITE</value></criteria><criteria><column name="applicant_reference" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">TIERS</value></criteria></filter></candidate><aggregate type="count"><column name="ref_id"/><description locale="fr">Nombre de dossiers</description></aggregate><aggregate type="sum" cur="EUR"><column name="bg_liab_amt"/><description locale="fr">Total encours</description></aggregate><executable_flag>Y</executable_flag></listdef>}'
FROM DUAL)
SELECT
    SUBSTR(YOUR_COL, 1, STARTPOS) || SUBSTR(YOUR_COL, ENDPOS) AS OUTPUT
FROM (
        SELECT
            YOUR_COL,
            INSTR(YOUR_COL, '<column width="5%" name="action">') - 1 AS STARTPOS,
            INSTR(YOUR_COL, 'name="SCREEN"/></url></column>') + 30 AS ENDPOS
        FROM  YOUR_TABLE
    );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7eb8f16c4b3ee7dead92179478dd0497)

Cheers!!

Comment: This will not work if the sub-string is matched in other (valid) places in the input [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0db71bc0c86f5e743308847752a7019f) and it will also fail if the order of the attributes is changed.

Comment: Yes, solution is made according to sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()` and `replace()` functions together :

```
select replace( str, 
                regexp_substr(str,'(<column width="5%")(.*)(</url></column>)')
              ) as "Extracted String"
  from tab
```

where `tab` denotes your original table and `str` does column of it containing the long string data shared.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1360a242f738969a0897bdff8700e867)</kbd>

Comment: This does not remove the desired part of the string and leave the rest as the OP requested. Also, the regular expression can match too much [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e226067e6b2208227d250764ab8a5e47).

Comment: the result of this query is what i want to delete not to keep

Comment: Excuse me @Blue I understood the logic in a complementary manner. Now fixed.

Comment: It can still delete too much [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b65e27e017d589d936ab2763afbb5a9) and will also fail if the `name` attribute is before the `width` attribute (which would make no difference to the meaning of the HTML/XML).

Answer (score 1):

If your value is syntactically valid XML/XHTML then you can convert it to an `XMLTYPE` and use `DELETEXML` to remove the `column` tag with the `name` attribute equal to `"action"`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT q'{<listdef page="25" default_order="entity" default_order_type="a"><reportId>1332</reportId><name>test</name><description>test</description><multiProduct>N</multiProduct><product_code>BG,</product_code><equivalentCurrency>EUR</equivalentCurrency><use_absolute_width>Y</use_absolute_width><column name="ref_id"><description locale="fr">Système Id</description></column><column name="iss_date"><description locale="fr">Date d'émission</description></column><column name="exp_date"><description locale="fr">Date de Validité</description></column><column name="bg_amt"><description locale="fr">Montant de la Garantie Bancaire</description></column><column name="applicant_name"><description locale="fr">Nom du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column name="entity"><description locale="fr">Entité</description></column><column name="applicant_reference"><description locale="fr">Référence du donneur d'ordre</description></column><column width="5%" name="action"><url action="y"><parameter column="ref_id" name="REFERENCE_ID"/><parameter column="product_code" name="PRODUCT_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="HISTORY" name="OPTION_CODE"/><parameter binding_code="LIST_INQUIRY" name="OPERATION_CODE"/><parameter value="TRADEADMIN_SCREEN" name="SCREEN"/></url></column><column name="bg_liab_amt" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><column name="product_code" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><parameter input="y" name="ENTITE" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">ENTITE</description></parameter><parameter input="y" name="TIERS" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">TIERS</description></parameter><parameter name="export_list" file="stock CBC" type="export" file_name="stock CBC"/><candidate name="BG"><filter><criteria><column name="entity" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">ENTITE</value></criteria><criteria><column name="applicant_reference" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">TIERS</value></criteria></filter></candidate><aggregate type="count"><column name="ref_id"/><description locale="fr">Nombre de dossiers</description></aggregate><aggregate type="sum" cur="EUR"><column name="bg_liab_amt"/><description locale="fr">Total encours</description></aggregate><executable_flag>Y</executable_flag></listdef>}' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT DELETEXML( XMLTYPE( value ), '/listdef/column[@name="action"]' ).getStringVal()
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | DELETEXML(XMLTYPE(VALUE),'/LISTDEF/COLUMN[@NAME="ACTION"]').GETSTRINGVAL()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | <listdef page="25" default_order="entity" default_order_type="a"><reportId>1332</reportId><name>test</name><description>test</description><multiProduct>N</multiProduct><product_code>BG,</product_code><equivalentCurrency>EUR</equivalentCurrency><use_absolute_width>Y</use_absolute_width><column name="ref_id"><description locale="fr">Syst??me Id</description></column><column name="iss_date"><description locale="fr">Date d&apos;??mission</description></column><column name="exp_date"><description locale="fr">Date de Validit??</description></column><column name="bg_amt"><description locale="fr">Montant de la Garantie Bancaire</description></column><column name="applicant_name"><description locale="fr">Nom du donneur d&apos;ordre</description></column><column name="entity"><description locale="fr">Entit??</description></column><column name="applicant_reference"><description locale="fr">R??f??rence du donneur d&apos;ordre</description></column><column name="bg_liab_amt" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><column name="product_code" hidden="y"/><column name="ref_id" hidden="y"/><parameter input="y" name="ENTITE" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">ENTITE</description></parameter><parameter input="y" name="TIERS" size="" max_length=""><description locale="fr">TIERS</description></parameter><parameter name="export_list" file="stock CBC" type="export" file_name="stock CBC"/><candidate name="BG"><filter><criteria><column name="entity" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">ENTITE</value></criteria><criteria><column name="applicant_reference" type="String"/><operator type="like"/><value type="parameter">TIERS</value></criteria></filter></candidate><aggregate type="count"><column name="ref_id"/><description locale="fr">Nombre de dossiers</description></aggregate><aggregate type="sum" cur="EUR"><column name="bg_liab_amt"/><description locale="fr">Total encours</description></aggregate><executable_flag>Y</executable_flag></listdef> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d23882b50e6723e54b2ae9bdc0527112)*